# Google cloud text to speech silence at the beginning and at the end of generated mp3

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I need to quickly play several generated audio file from google cloud text to speech service.
Here is what i get:
https://yadi.sk/i/jbkGpd23bprmyw
As you see it has about 0.15-0.3 s silence at the beginning and at the end of mp3 data.
Is there a way to tell API not to include these silent parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffmpeg` to extract the portion of the audio clip you wish to keep.

For example, if you want the 0.5 seconds in the middle of a 0.8 second clip with 0.15s of silence at the beginning and end you set `-t 00:00:00.500` (length of audio to keep) and use `-ss 00:00:00.150` parameter at the beginning to set where to start.

Full command will look like this:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.150 -i ttsclip.mp3 -t 00:00:00.500 -acodec copy ttsclip-cut.mp3
```

Comment: I suspect they're looking for something that's more automated, without needing to measure the amount of silence for each file. That said, this might still be appropriate if the padding is a consistent amount.